# Persistent UDF Issue in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

Im creating a Persistent UDF in Bigquery.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `project.dataset.get_names_function`(x STRING) RETURNS STRING AS (
(
select string_agg( c.company_name,' | ') final_names
from `project.dataset.table1` b
inner join unnest(split(x, "|")) gbi 
ON (gbi = cast(b.globid as string)),
unnest(b.ind_ids) gid
inner join `project.dataset.table2` c
ON (gid = c.globind)
)
);
```

When i try to invoke it using hardcoded values it works fine.

```
SELECT `project.dataset.get_names_function`("12345|67890");

Result:
Managed Services | Combined Policy
```

But when i add it as part of select query of another table

```
select 
   `project.dataset.get_names_function`(product_ids)
from `project.dataset.test_table1`
```

it errors out stating:

```
Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.
```

Thanks you in advance for solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it works when hardcoded, have you tried using `DECLARE` and storing the results ahead of time? That way we can bypass the runtime evaluation that is causing the error.

Try:

`DECLARE product_ids STRING DEFAULT (SELECT product_ids from project.dataset.test_table1)`

And then pass this into the function.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, BigQuery does not support **[correlated subqueries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/subqueries#correlated_subquery_concepts)**.

These kinds of issues normally stem from the way the query you're trying to run was written. Sometimes queries break when they make many references to other tables in a cumbersome way. If you add **ORDER BY**, **LIMIT**,  **EXISTS**, **NOT EXISTS**, **IN** (table) clauses into correlated subqueries then most likely it won't work.

Normally re-writing the query in a more straightforward way or using less join statements can work. More information on how the join clause works can be found in this **[documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#join_types)**. Another workaround for correlated subquery issues is to use BigQuery's new **[scripting interface](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language)** which will let you CREATE TEMP TABLE on your substeps.

However, there is a **[feature request](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/71699514)** filed for the same. You can vote for this feature by clicking the `+1` and `STAR` mark to receive updates on it.